# Comparison Between Guided Filter (Edge Preserving Filter) and Gaussian Filter

Tags: image-processing, matlab, filters, computer-vision, edge-preserving-filter

I am looking for a good example that showing the different between Guided and Gaussian Filters. The example need to show the benefit of Guided filter, (for example: preserving edge...). Could you give me some example for that task? Thanks in advance

I tried some example, but it did not show benefit of Guided comparison with Gaussian

```
% example: edge-preserving smoothing
% figure 1 in our paper

close all;

I = double(imread('.\img_smoothing\cat.bmp')) / 255;
I = imnoise(I,'gaussian',0.1,0);
p = I;
r = 4; % try r=2, 4, or 8
eps = 0.2^2; % try eps=0.1^2, 0.2^2, 0.4^2

q = guidedfilter(I, p, r, eps);
std_Gb=1;
beta=0.1;
%% Initialization 
Ng=ceil(3*std_Gb)+1; Gaussian = fspecial('gaussian',[Ng Ng],std_Gb);
imsm = conv2(I,Gaussian,'same');

[Gx,Gy] = gradient(q );
NormGrad = sqrt(Gx.^2 + Gy.^2); 
Gb1 = 1./ (1 + 1* NormGrad.^2);

[Gx,Gy] = gradient(imsm);
NormGrad = sqrt(Gx.^2 + Gy.^2); 
Gb2= 1./ (1 + 1* NormGrad.^2);

figure();
subplot(2,1,1);imshow([I, q,imsm],[]);
subplot(2,1,2);imshow([Gb1,Gb2],[]);
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create  a synthetic image with abrupt change form black to white (Better yest from Dark Gray to Bright Gray).
2. Add Gaussian Noise to it.
3. Filter it with Guided Filter and Gaussian Filter.
4. Look at the results.
5. Draw a 1D Line which crosses it and look at the Original, Noisy, Filters Guided, Filtered Gaussian.

Here are the results:

**Noisy Image**

[image: Noisy Image]

[image: Lines - Noisy Image]

**Gaussian Filtered Image**

[image: Gaussian Filtered Image]

[image: Lines - Gaussian Filtered Image]

**Guided Filtered Image**

[image: Guided Filtered Image]

[image: Lines - Guided Filtered Image]

As one could see, the Gaussian Filter smooth the image across high contrast edges while the Guided Filter keep the edges.

The MATLAB code is available at my [StackExchange Signal Processing Q29041 GitHub Repository](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/StackExchangeCodes) (Look at the `SignalProcessing\Q29041` folder).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Would you add the matlab code for better visualization.

Comment: I added MATLAB Code and visualization. Enjoy...

Comment: It is really good ans. Could you suggest to me how can I choose the radius and var. para. of Guided filter when noise increasing? Does it still has benefit  for other kind of noise or just Gaussian noise?

Comment: The larger the radius, you can deal with lower frequency noise. Basically, it will work pretty good with any White Noise (Assuming it has Zero Mean).

Comment: Thank you. If I consider Gaussian noise with (zero mean, and variance v), then lower frequency noise means low variance v. Is it right?

Comment: No, if you model White noise it means its energy is uniformly spread all over the frequency range.

Comment: So, in case of Gaussian noise with (zero mean, and variance v), if the variance is increase, how can I choose the sigma and radius of Guided filter? And What is happen if I set RADIUS_TO_STD_FACTOR    = 0.3; in your code. The results of Gaussian and Guided filter looks same. Thanks