# Implementation of a Separable Bilateral Filter for Edge Preserving Smoothing

Tags: image-processing, software-implementation, edge-preserving-filter, separability, julia

I’m trying to optimize my naively implemented O(n^2) bilateral filter for 2D images. I googled and found a lot of theoretical explanations about the separate one. However, it seems there are things that should be taken special care of, regarding to the normalization.

I’m wondering if there are good references for especially the implementation?

Comment: Separable Bilateral Filter is quite simple to implement. Would you like a MATLAB code for that?

Comment: Yes I'd like to see a matlab code. I actually think there should be only a simple two pass 1D convolution and no extra attention should be made...

Answer (score 1):

The idea is the same as any other separable filter:

- Work on the columns / rows of the image.
- Work on the rows / columns of the output of the previous step.

In Julia it will be something like:

```
function BilateralFilter!( vO :: AbstractVector{T}, vI :: AbstractVector{T}, vB :: AbstractVector{T}, σₛ :: T, σₖ :: T, filterRadius :: U ) where{T <: AbstractFloat, U <: Unsigned}
    
    numElements = length(vI);

    vB .= vI;

    for kk in 1:numElements
        leftRadius  = max(1, kk - filterRadius);
        rightRadius = min(numElements, kk + filterRadius);
        sumPx       = zero(T);
        sumW        = zero(T);
        for ii in leftRadius:rightRadius
            wⱼ     = exp( -0.5 * (((ii - kk) ^ 2) / (σₛ * σₛ)) -0.5 *  (((vI[ii] - vI[kk]) ^ 2) / (σₖ * σₖ)) )
            sumW  += wⱼ;
            sumPx += wⱼ * vI[ii];
        end
        vO[kk] = sumPx / sumW;
    end

end

function BilateralFilter!( mO :: Matrix{T}, mI :: Matrix{T}, σₛ :: T, σₖ :: T, filterRadius :: U ) where{T <: AbstractFloat, U <: Unsigned}
    
    numRows, numCols = size(mI);

    vB = Vector{T}(undef, max(numRows, numCols)); #<! Buffer for the in place operation

    for jj = 1:numCols
        @views BilateralFilter!(mO[:, jj], mI[:, jj], vB, σₛ, σₖ, filterRadius);
    end
    for ii = 1:numRows
        @views BilateralFilter!(mO[ii, :], mO[ii, :], vB, σₛ, σₖ, filterRadius);
    end

end
```

So, as you can see in the function which operates on the `Matrix{T}`, we first apply the 1D [Bilateral Filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilateral_filter) to column of the input `mI` and save it to `mO`. Then we operate on `mO`'s rows in place.

Since we work *in place* we must keep a buffer of the input (`vB`).

The output is not as good as the 2D [Bilateral Filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilateral_filter) yet it is achieved much faster indeed.
You may and should [validate the Bilateral Filter](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/24610).

I'd mention there are many other alternatives.
Some are approximation of the Bilateral Filter (Usually by going to higher dimension and applying convolution) or just other efficient Edge Preserving filters:

- [Guided Filter](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/29041).
- [Simple Image Edge Preserving Filter](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/74674).
- [Real Time Edge Aware Image Processing with the Bilateral Grid](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/1276377.1276506).

The code is available at my [StackExchange Codes Signal Processing GitHub Repository](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/StackExchangeCodes) (Look at the `SignalProcessing\Q56490` folder).